# JSON Parsing issue - Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing

So i have build a REST Client that returns JSON response. However, i have an issue, where the JSON output is not exactly what i need:
Current Response:

```
{
    "output": {
        "status": "Device 'Test' does not exist",
        "result": "null",
        "response": {
            "output": "success",
            "result": 204
        }
    }
}
```

This output has an outermost enclosing "output" key, but i don't want that to be present. So basically i want my response to look like below:

```
{
    "status": "Device 'Test' does not exist",
    "result": "null",
    "response": {
        "output": "success",
        "result": 204
    }
}
```

I did try converting the JSON to Dict and then remove it, but no luck? any suggestions how to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the code that generates this json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your response is already a dictionary or a json object then you can do following

```
value_required = response["output"]
```

if it is in text format (which I think it is) then you just need to do the following

```
import json
value_required = json.loads(response)["output"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
response = json.loads(response)['output']
```